# Implementing different layer 2 solutions for Ethereum

Tags: blockchain, ethereum, layer-2

im writing my Bachelor Thesis in Computer Science about Blockchain and Ethereium in general. My aim is to benchmark/analyze the Transactions per second by creating private Ethereum.

In order to benchmark/analyze im was thinking that i should create three Eth networks and each having one specific solution for scalability..

Different solution implementation:

```
One eth network has sidechain as consensus layer solution
One eth network has Rollups as consensus layer solution
One eth network has sharding as consensus layer solution
```

How realistic are these implementations, how would i even start?

Keep in mind im writing a Bachelor Thesis, meaning its not going to be at a very high level.

Comment: StackOverflow is focused on programming questions (e.g. about smart contract code executable on the Ethereum network). You might get better answers at the [Ethereum StackExchange](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: i am asking a programming question? @PetrHejda

Comment: Usually other questions tagged Ethereum here at StackOverflow are more about smart contract source code - in languages like Solidity, Yul, Vyper - and algorithms related to smart contracts... From my point of view, this question is more about the Ethereum network architecture rather than code. So I'm assuming that answerers here (including me) don't have that deep knowledge of this subtopic and won't be able to provide good answers. That's why I linked the StackExchange - there you might get answers from people who are more focused on the topic you're asking about.